# CCArray vs. std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, cocos2d-x

I understand that you can just use std::vector or even normal arrays for non-CCObject objects, and use CCArray otherwise. But what if I have a class that is a wrapper of a CCObject? can I store it in a std::vector, adding (wrapper constructor) or removing (wrapper destructor) that CCObject as a child of a layer with no issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store pointer to CCObject in std::vector, but you must remember about retain when you add object to vector and release when you release when you remove from vector.

Comment: Is it really necessary if I do     

constructor:
LAYER->addChild(m_pSprite, 0);

destructor:
LAYER->removeChild(m_pSprite, 0); ?

Comment: In this case this isn't necessary because addChild call retain and removeChild call release